# Array is not updating properly java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a program that hosts a tournament. the first part is a group stage where players play each other twice. I created a Group class and a players class. A group consists of a group number and an array of players. Each player has an ID, name, wins, draws losses and points.

I have created the groups fine along with fixtures for the group.

```
Group Number: 15        W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Louetta(2)           0       0       0       0
3) Tomiko(3)            0       0       0       0
4) Patti(4)             0       0       0       0
5) Lea(5)               0       0       0       0
6) Nannie(6)            0       0       0       0


Group Number: 16        W       D       L       Pts
1) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Shantell(2)          0       0       0       0
3) Amalia(3)            0       0       0       0
4) Zella(4)             0       0       0       0
5) Alleen(5)            0       0       0       0
6) Tameika(6)           0       0       0       0
```

What I am trying to do next is take the winning player from each group to progress them to the next round. Which will create a new Group Array.

```
public static void progressGroup(Group[] group, Group[] secondRound){

    int gn = 1;
    //2 players per group
    Players[] players = new Players[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < group.length-1; i++){
        //get players at first and second positions from each group
        players[0] = group[i].getPlayer(0);
        players[1] = group[i+1].getPlayer(0);      
        //make group
        secondRound[i] = createGroup(gn, players);
        //incerement group number
        gn++;
    }
    //debuging
    for(int i = 0; i < secondRound.length; i++){
        System.out.println(groupStage[i].toString());
    }
}
```

But I think im missing something. The new Group Array(next round of tournament) populates all groups with the winning player from the last and second last groups.

```
Group Number: 1         W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0

Group Number: 2         W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0

Group Number: 3         W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0

Group Number: 4         W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0

Group Number: 5         W       D       L       Pts
1) Cinthia(1)           0       0       0       0
2) Calista(1)           0       0       0       0
```

Anybody have any suggestions or can spot something small? Thank you

Comment: Please include your code *in the question*, not as an image.

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Thank you. Hope this makes it easier to read. Other images are just output.

Comment: add `Players[] players = new Players[2];` into the `for` statement block. Also, increment the index by 2: `for(int i = 0; i < group.length-1; i += 2) {`

Comment: Thanks @Jorj that worked to an extent. I created a new counter, j for secondRound[j] = createGroup(gn, players);.  Now I have the problem of the new group array  only being created with 8 groups as i is being doubled everytime. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Robbie: Can you show how the `Group[]` arrays are created and passed in? Actually, I would recommend trying to create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem -- I suspect that the actual bug is in code that you haven't shown.

Comment: @Robbie, it's not what you want? From 16 groups take all winners, meaning 16 players, and group them by two resulting 8 groups of 2 players, right?

Comment: Sorry @Jorj my mistake, What I'm meant to be doing is taking the winner from one group and match them in a group with the runners up from another. So need to change my code now that I showed you –

Comment: @Jorj Ok i've come up with something but I know it is not a good solution but it works, which is what I want for the moment. I'll edit the post to show you if you want. Thank you for your help